# We found a dove. How do we care for it?

Tags: birds, age

We found one dove from outside so I want to know how old this bird is and what I can do for it?

I searched the internet and, based on it's [photo shown](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&biw=360&bih=512&sxsrf=ACYBGNSRXAQCkgDvY3UYkuXGKguM6sNRtg:1569181481350&ei=Kc-HXYDkFIXPwQLL8pTQCQ&q=bird%20find%20dove%20age%20r&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAnKLGmOXkAhWFZ1AKHUs5BZoQ7Al6BAgCEAI&biw=360&bih=512) below, I think it must be an adult. 
[image]

This [link](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&q=adult%20%20%20dove%20eat&oq=adult%20%20%20dove%20eat&aqs=heirloom-srp..) suggests feeding carrots:

> Doves should be offered fresh fruits and vegetables alongside seeds
>   and pellets. These add diversity to the bird's diet and give it a wide
>   variety of nutrients. Some items to give your dove include lettuce,
>   kale, broccoli, carrots, and apples

The photo of this bird shown below:

[image]

And

[image]

How long does it need to stay with me and what care does it need?

**Update:**

It has been better, although one week ago when I let it to try flying in my room, it's left wing has been fixed but now it has been stopped.

I am scared and haven't let it try flying in my room again so I put it in a cage in our house yard. Here are some pictures of it:

[image]

And this is its food (Is this enough / too much?):

[image]

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some feedback on this question.

Comment: It seems to hold it's wing at an odd angle. There might be a broken bone in it's left wing, but I might be wrong. If there is a veterinarian or animal rescue center available, you should ask them for help. Worst case is that the bone doesn't grow back together correctly and the bird won't be able to fly long distances or ever again.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for taking care of this bird. An adult dove is about the same size as a pigeon. Compared to the newspaper's scale, the dove seems to be fully grown.

Indeed, feeding a few fruits and vegetables can be beneficial for the animal. But the bird should only consume those types of foods occasionally as doves mostly eat dry food. Small dried fruits such as raisins are nice little treats. Seeds and pellets are fine in any quantity.

You should keep the bird until its able to fly on its own again. Once per day, you can encourage the bird to try and fly away by having it in your hands and extanding your arms when outside. Your own height is sufficient; do not try this from a window. If the dove cannot yet fly, they will fall to the ground and hurt themselves.

A word of caution, though. Doves are currently in their fall migration, so the bird was perhaps abandoned by their flock because of weak health. In addition, birds are very sensitive to stress and the little guy is probably quite unhappy to have been left behind. So do not feel guilty if the bird dies in the next few days, chances are it won't be your fault at all.

Still, be sure to keep the dove in a warm room with plenty of food and water. Placing newspapers was a good idea, make sure the whole room is covered to avoid stains of bird feces on your furniture.

Comment: If there's an issue with the wing, as suggested in the comments, can the wing heal of its own accord or will it need some professional attention?

Comment: Tomorrow I found that this bird has a disability on its left leg, so my brother heard of his friend which is veterinarian in another city that may be the crows have attacked to it and hurt it. So is there any help that, can I do for it?

Comment: It' new healt situation. 