# Refugee lovebird with difficulty walking

Tags: health, birds, parrots

We suddenly found this refugee lovebird with walking difficulty at our home. I think the bird must have been hurt by falling down form high level of building and its leg has broken:

[image]

[image]

I have this two medicines from [another bird with walking problem](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26194/we-found-a-dove-how-do-we-care-for-it), which was cured, similar to these:

- [Multivitamin Drops for Babies](https://www.darukade.com/products/supplement-boost-baby-growth-320/drops-multivitamin-drops-for-babies-13927):

[image]

- [Osteocare 200 ml](https://www.darukade.com/products/supplement-bone-strengthening-and-growth-1158/syrup-osteocare-200-ml-1247) :

[image]

I will appreciate your suggestions on how could I help her/him for its walking problem.

**Update:**

I bring it to a vet and he said it is weak because of being lost and will become better, also give it B complex and multi vitamin.

So we hope it become better.

What can we do to help it's recovery?

Comment: Poor little bird. Is there any chance you can take it to a vet?

Comment: Thanks @Yvette_colomb it is done, and add more details as update at Q.